# Two results in one row using the same ID

Tags: sql, oracle

Table structures:
**Fruit:**

```
| fID | fName | fAmount | SpeciesID |
|-----|-------|---------|-----------|
| 1   | Apple | 22      | 1         |
| 2   | Pear  | 4       | 1         |
| 3   | Grape | 5       | 1         |
```

**Species:**

```
| SpeciesID | SpeciesName | SpeciesPrice |
|-----------|-------------|--------------|
| 1         | Fruit       | 100          |
```

**Parent:**

```
| pID       | fID | ParentIDa | ParentIDb | Colour |
|-----------|-----|-----------|-----------|--------|
| 1         | 1   | 2         | 3         | Red    |
```

The output I want to achieve:

```
| fName | fAmount | SpeciesName | SpeciesPrice | Colour | fID | fName | SpeciesName | SpeciesPrice |
|-------|:-------:|-------------|--------------|--------|-----|-------|-------------|--------------|
| Apple |    22   | Fruit       | 100          | Red    | 2   | Pear  | Fruit       | 100          |
| Apple |    22   | Fruit       | 100          | Red    | 3   | Grape | Fruit       | 100          |
```

The first 5 columns are for the child, Colour taken from Parent table.
The most important part now, I need to use the ParentIDa (first result) and ParentIDb (for 2nd result) to be added to the columns using the Fruit table and fID again then JOIN the Species for the parents table as well.

In short, some of the fruits have parents, that are listed in the Parent table, I want to display the child info first, then Parent1 info and the second result should same child info + Parent2 info.

This is what I got so far:

```
SELECT  fName,fAmount,SpeciesName,SpeciesPrice,Colour,fID,sub.*
FROM Fruit f 
INNER JOIN Parent pa ON (f.fID = pa.fID) 
INNER JOIN Species s ON (a.SpeciesID = s.SpeciesID)
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT fID,fName,SpeciesID 
    FROM Fruit 
    WHERE pa.ParentIDa = f.fID) sub;
```

I just can't get the inner query working, I need to somehow use the main fID outputted to use it for the subquery.

Comment: From where did you get `avatarID`?

Comment: Sorry, should be f.fID. Fixed.

Comment: Check It now. Updated my answer.

Comment: @ZenkTM I used sqlFiddle for your question and output is just you describe.. Whatelse you need? or what's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Think the problem is in sub select you cannot refer to external query. Try not to do sub select but just JOIN with Fruit in last statement and assign another alias for this table.

```
INNER JOIN Fruit f2 WHERE pa.ParentIDa = f2.avatarID
```

Answer (score 1):

I used sqlFiddle for your question, please see editted  [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3c4b0/35)

Your exact output is:

```
SELECT f.fName,f.fAmount,s.SpeciesName,s.SpeciesPrice, p.Colour, f.fID, f.fName, s.SpeciesName, s.SpeciesPrice 
FROM Fruit f 
INNER JOIN Species s ON f.SpeciesID = s.SpeciesID
INNER JOIN Parent p ON f.fID != p.fID
```

if you want to see equal id use ;

```
INNER JOIN Parent p ON f.fID = p.fID
```

When you use != operator output is :

```
Pear    4   Fruit   100 Red 2   Pear    Fruit   100
Grape   5   Fruit   100 Red 3   Grape   Fruit   100
```

If you use = operator output is :

```
Apple   22  Fruit   100 Red 1   Apple   Fruit   100
```

**EDIT:** ParentIDa and ParentIDb joint.

```
SELECT f.fName,f.fAmount,s.SpeciesName,s.SpeciesPrice, p.Colour, f.fID, f.fName, s.SpeciesName, s.SpeciesPrice 
FROM Fruit f 
INNER JOIN Parent p ON (p.ParentIDa = f.fID or p.ParentIDb = f.fID)
INNER JOIN Species s ON f.SpeciesID = s.SpeciesID;
```

Comment: There are going to be more records in the tables, so I cannot use the != operator, I need to use the parentIDa = fID or parentIDb = fID.

Comment: @ZenkTM Did you check my link there is also f.fID = p.fID solution

Comment: Yeah, the ParentIDs are also not joined.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that what you need?

```
SELECT f.fName,f.fAmount,s.SpeciesName,s.SpeciesPrice, pa.Colour, f.fID, f.fName, s.SpeciesName, s.SpeciesPrice 
FROM Fruit f 
INNER JOIN Parent pa ON f.fID = pa.fID 
INNER JOIN Species s ON f.SpeciesID = s.SpeciesID
WHERE pa.ParentIDa = f.fID
```

or

```
SELECT f.fName,f.fAmount,s.SpeciesName,s.SpeciesPrice, pa.Colour, f.fID, f.fName, s.SpeciesName, s.SpeciesPrice 
FROM Fruit f 
INNER JOIN Parent pa ON f.fID = pa.fID AND pa.ParentIDa = f.fID
INNER JOIN Species s ON f.SpeciesID = s.SpeciesID
```

Comment: That will not show the parent in the same result, pa.ParentIDa = f.fID

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, got the answer now:

```
SELECT f.fName,f.fAmount,s.SpeciesName,s.SpeciesPrice, p.Colour, f2.fID, f2.fName, f2.SpeciesID, s2.SpeciesName, s2.SpeciesPrice
FROM Fruit f 
INNER JOIN Species s ON f.SpeciesID = s.SpeciesID
INNER JOIN Parent p ON f.fID = p.fID
INNER JOIN Fruit f2 ON p.ParentIDa = f2.fID OR p.ParentIDb = f2.fID
INNER JOIN Species s2 ON f2.SpeciesID = s2.SpeciesID;
```

See [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/595e5/3)

Comment: sqlFiddle always best for such tasks, but I see you stole all create table codes :)